# How to find program asking permission to make changes to your computer

Tags: windows-10

A program keeps asking to make changes to my computer.  I don't know this program and always answer no.  I copy the file location of the program to delete it but when I ask search to find it for me it comes back with no results.

Comment: Can you you provide a screenshot of the warning pop-up? Normally the program is listed on there.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. First is to look through `Task Manager` to see what is currently running.

Sometimes programs will leave some trace within `Event Viewer` so it may be worth looking through

Depending on when it shows up, it could be that is begins as your PC boots or up or at regular intervals, so search in the `start up` tab of `Task Manager` or if it's in `Task Scheduler`